# Add removed/deprecated functions to PHP5

Tags: php, deprecated

Is it possible to add a removed/deprecated function to PHP5? Like `session_is_registered`, `ereg`, etc.

---

[update] solved for session_is_registered:

```
<?php
function session_is_registered($name) {
    return isset($_SESSION[$name]);
}
```

thanks.

Comment: Do you mean php native functions or user-defined functions. I wonder why you need to bring deprecated function back to your php-version. There is no need for that.

Comment: That is possible if you fetch the sources and compile them yourself after having re-integrated those features from older versions. However you really do not want to do that: besides that it takes a huge effort please consider that there are very good reasons why certain functions are deprecated and removed. There _always_ are very good replacements available. Instead of wasting your time, money and power to outdated stuff, invest into the future instead.

Comment: @Mubo `session_is_registered` and `ereg` are native.

Comment: Why you want to do this? They are deprecated for a reason use `isset($_SESSION['test']);` or similair instead.

Comment: I don't know. It's just crossed in my mind. @arkascha : I'll try it.
thank you for your attention guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can do it by modifying and recompiling the PHP source code, however the first question you have to answer is *Do I really need to this or I might be better to go for my IDE's find-and-replace function?*

If there is a real need for this -- for whatever reason, maybe you can redefine those functions. I haven't test it yet, as I agree with others that functions and features get removed or deprecated for a good and mostly important reasons, so I'm not sure if it does work in a situation that the function is removed or depreciated, but you can try to redefine them either using [runkit_function_redefine](http://us.php.net/runkit_function_redefine) or 
[override_function](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php).

In that case you have to simulate the functionality again -- probably with their good-to-go replacements, so again think twice before start doing that.